# How to use sultry?

Tags: word-usage

> Sultry: very hot and humid

That is the meaning of sultry I am familiar with and have seen used in books. However Merriam - Webster Dictionary has another meaning

> 2 a : hot with passion or **anger**

How can sultry be used in a sentence with the sense of anger?
Would "He left the room in a sultry rage" be correct, or "She screamed at him in a sultry temper"?

Comment: I would prefer these definitions [***sultry***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/sultry). There is no "anger" here, though sometimes the "passion or lust" has a nefarious purpose, such as to get revenge on some poor guy.

Comment: **Sultry** is to **simmering** what **anger** is to **boiling** to use cooking analogies, but there is no anger in **sultry**, it usually has a **seductive** meaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oald's definition is better. Sultry weather can make you feel uncomfortable.
A sensual and sexy woman can have the same effect if she is too eager to have sex.
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sultry?q=sultry

Comment: That's one sweltering lady friend you got there.